# AWS CDK Python - Passing in variables from config.py into lambda.funtion environment option

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am attempting to create a Lambda function adding in environment variables from a config.py file.  The variables are created in the `config.py` file using dict(). I tried using **kwargs.get('variable_from_configpy_file')** but that errored out with **Got 'undefined' for non-optional instance of {"type":{"primitive":"string"}}**. How can I import the variable values from the config.py file into the environment option of the lambda.funtion (environment={"key": "value",...})? I'm new to python so any ideas would be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the relevant portions of your `config.py` and the CDK code where you're creating the lambda?

Comment: Thanks for the inquiry @maafk.  I was able to resolve my problem by using the posted code.  I appreciate you assisting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to using stackoverflow and I promise I'll get better.  Below is what worked for me and the associated config.py and stack code.  Thanks again to all who engaged.

**Config.py**

```
workspaces_lifecycle_lambda_stack = dict(
    DirectoryID='ourDirectoryId',
    BundleID='ourBundleId',
    UsersBucketName='arn:aws-partition:s3:::ourBucketName'
)
```

**Stack code**

```
    workspaces_lambda = lambda_.Function(
        self, "WorkspacesUsersCompare",
        code=lambda_.Code.asset(
            "./workspaces_lifecycle_app/lambdas/lambda_compare.zip"),
        handler="index.lambda_handler",
        timeout=core.Duration.seconds(600),
        runtime=lambda_.Runtime.PYTHON_2_7,
        role=workspaces_lifecycle_roles.get('lc_role'),
        )

    workspaces_lambda.add_environment(
        'DIRECTORY_ID', kwargs.get('DirectoryID')
    )

    workspaces_lambda.add_environment(
        'BUNDLE_ID', kwargs.get('BundleID')
    )
```